# How to make a usb bootable ubunut 20.04 lts image

Tags: ubuntu

I have ubuntu 20.04 lts on my system already installed. I forgot the admin password

I am planning to make a bootable usb drive.

I see ubuntu 20.04 is 3.1 Gb. I just need to reset the password, so i dont want to download  such a large img for booting purpose

Is there any small ubunut 20.04 bootable image which shows only command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to boot a live OS to recover an Ubuntu password:

### The Standard Way

This procedure gives you a full root shell! You can damage your system if you are not careful!

When booting up press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (in systems 9.10 "karmic" or later) or <kbd>ESC</kbd> (in systems 9.04 "jaunty" or earlier) at the grub prompt and use the arrow keys to select the rescue mode option and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
The file system may be read only (it is in all currently supported releases). Remount as read write

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

This will boot the system in rescue mode and you should arrive at a prompt that looks like this

```
root@something
```

To reset your password type this in

```
passwd <username>
```

Press return, then you will be prompted to <kbd>enter</kbd> and confirm a new password.
Once you are done resetting your password you can than switch back to the normal GUI mode by putting this in

```
init 2
```

If if appears to boot normally, but you see a message that says:

Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):

then you will have to try a different trick below.

#### The Other Way

If the "Standard Way" does not work for you and you recieve the "Give root password for maintenance" message, you can recover your password using the following steps

1. Reboot your computer
2. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> at the grub prompt (as earlier).
3. Select your image.
4. Highlight the line that begins kernel and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit
5. Go to the very end of the line, change the `ro` to `rw` and add `init=/bin/bash` press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>b</kbd> to boot your system.

Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.

6. Type in `passwd username`
7. Set your password.
8. Type in `reboot`

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20220106050855/https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)